# Best practices for passing data from one angular module to another, in different HTML pages

Tags: angularjs

I have an API that manages Lab, now I'm trying to develop a Form Manager, form quotations, orders, etc. 
Since I will add Metalwork in the future, and for OO principles, I would like to have the Forms separated from the 'Works'.
But, say I select several items from the Lab, and want to make a quotation, I should somehow pass them to the Form Manager.
Also, the status of the item should be updated once the form is submitted.

Solutions:

1. Storing the data in an intermediate service?
2. Push it to a local (Lab or Form) service? Seems odd, because forms will have to know about lab and vice versa.
3. Pushing to the server via an API into a temporary collection and removing from there once finished?

Comment: Sorry for poor markup, I'm on the phone.

Comment: Id say store the whole registration in an intermediate service which holds all the data. Then the forms can be separated as much as you like, but as soon as one of them saves, the data gets stored in the service.

Comment: There are many ways to do this like, one is $rootscope, second is local storage, third one is session storage, choose one of this, this all are having their own properties and attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to store the data inside a "model" like `.factory()` and consume it.

Example:

```
/* models.js */

import angular from 'angular';

import User from 'models/User';

const models = angular.module('app.models', []);

models
  .factory('UserModel', User);

export default models;


/* user.js */

function User (dependencies) {
  let User;

  return {
    setProperties(user),
    getProperties(User),
  }
}
export default User;


/* controller 1 */

function Controller1(UserModel) {
  UserModel.setProperties($scope.model);
}
export default Controller1;


/* controller 2 */

function Controller2(UserModel) {
  UserModel.getProperties();
}
export default Controller2;
```